# default sorting not working in jquery datatable on serverside processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is the js code that I use. I want to have column 2 sorted in descending order by default.
when I disable bserverside to be false, I get this working (but it does not show all the records when I click next page).

However, if I  enable `bserverside:true`, I get the what I have shown below in the image. if I remove "aaSorting", but keep `bserverside:true`, it displays all records on pagination. but the records are not sorted and clicking the sort button on the column header does not sort. Moreover, sorting on other columns (which I have included in aocolumns) produce the same image. I cannot figure out what is going wrong. I spent entire weekend trying to figure this out. but have not made any progress yet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#search_table').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lrtip',
        "bProcessing": true,
        //"bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "{% url 'search_list_json' %}",
        "aaSorting": [ [2,"desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength":10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sClass": "center", "sWidth": "15%","bSortable": false  },
            { "sClass": "center", "sWidth": "5%","bSortable": true },
            { "sClass": "center", "sWidth": "5%","bSortable": true },
            { "sClass": "center", "sWidth": "5%" ,"bSortable": true },
            { "sClass": "center", "sWidth": "5%","bSortable": false}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

[image]

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot I only see 4 columns, but your aoColumns array has 5 entries.  Is the fifth column there and just got cut off from the screen capture?

Answer (score 0):

**Following code is working for me** 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var dataTable = $('#employee_data').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "aaSorting": [ [0,"desc" ]],
    "ajax": {
        url: "$urlOne",
        type: "post",
        error: function()
        {
           alert('error');
        }

    }
});
```